# How to make my DB query function more speed-efficient without sacrificing convenience

Tags: r, database, performance

I wrote a function to more conveniently access the database I use at work: rather than needing to type traditional SQL commands, I can just list the name of a table in the database, and the function will automatically load the full table into R, which I assign to a dataframe. When it's loaded, certain columns with types like *date* and *logical* show up as *integer* or *character* that way, so my function also identifies and re-casts them.

Unfortunately, lately my queries have been running more slowly, and in some cases not even completing. I don't know if this is because of a database issue or a code issue, but I only really have control over the latter, so I figured I'd get some feedback and find out if I can make some parts more efficient. One part that I **know** is not efficient is the * part of the query - I rarely need every column, but I often don't know which ones I'll need ahead of time, and since there are many different tables I can load in, * is the only select statement I know will work for all of them. I'm open to any *other* efficiency insights, though. I'll walk through the function:

```
GetFinderTable <- function(table) {
  if (missing(table))
    stop("ERROR: Table missing")
  if (!table %in% c(*table names*))
    stop("ERROR: Table not found in Finder Database")
  query <- "*"
```

The first part of the function does basic error checking to ensure that the table name exists and is one of the tables in the database. I assign the * value to "query" - I've thought about expanding this to provide other column names for this variable, but that would be very table-dependent.

```
  LoadPackages(c('DBI', 'RMySQL', 'glue', 'magrittr', 'rlist'))
  db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = -private-, password = -private-, host = -private-, dbname = -private-)
  df <- dbGetQuery(db, glue('select {query} from {table}'))
  dbDisconnect(db)
```

*LoadPackages* is another custom function I wrote to streamline package management - it will install, update or attach the listed packages as needed. No matter who's running this script, the necessary packages will be installed. the next three lines actually query the database. I used *glue* because it's more convenient, but I wonder if that's less efficient compared to *paste*.

```
  cols <- apply(df, 2, function(x) (grepl("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]$", na.omit(x)) %>% all)) 
  %>% which
  size <- length(cols)
  if (size > 0) {
    if (size == 1)
      df[,cols] %<>% as.Date
    else
      df[,cols] %<>% lapply(as.Date)
  }
  cols <- apply(df, 2, function(x) (grepl("^[0-1]$", na.omit(x)) %>% all)) %>% which %>% 
    list.append(apply(df, 2, function(x) (grepl("False|True", na.omit(x)) %>% all)) %>% which)
  size <- length(cols)
  if (size > 0) {
    if (size == 1)
      df[,cols] %<>% as.logical
    else
      df[,cols] %<>% lapply(as.logical)
   }
  return(df) 
}
```

Here's where I'm hoping to make some efficiency gains. These next few lines isolate the date columns (by checking whether they match R's date format) and the logical columns (by seeing whether the columns exclusively contain 0 and 1 or "True" and "False"). I accidentally discovered the danger of using lapply where there's only one column that needs recasting, hence why I have the *if* condition. After the recasting, the dataframe is returned.

Any insights into how to make the function more efficient would be much appreciated. I spend way too long waiting for these queries to complete!

Comment: Just a few comments: *" I wonder if that's [`glue`] less efficient compared to `paste`"* - this is the wrong idea. Regardless of which of these is more efficient, I'm sure they are accounting for less than 0.1% of the run time of this script. Find an alternative that's 10 times faster than `paste` or `glue` and you'll save your self .09% of your run time. Focus only on the actual performance bottlenecks. Similarly, your `LoadPackages` is irrelevant to this question (unless it's buggy and re-installs packages that are present).

Comment: Where do you think the bottlenecks are?

Comment: Using `apply` on a data frame is inefficient - `apply` is made for use on matrices, so the first thing it does to a data frame is convert it to a matrix, which, if you have any non-numeric columns, means converting everything to `character` class. I have no idea what you mean about "the danger of using lapply where there's only one column" (maybe you need to use the `df[] = lapply(df, ...)` idiom?), but `apply` is bad for this case

Comment: In general, look up "code profiling" for how to identify bottlenecks. There are at least a couple packages for that, and [here's the Advanced R section on profiling](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html).

Comment: Thank you - that's helpful. What function should I use instead of `apply` to iterate across columns of a dataframe?

Comment: It looks like, for example in your date checking, your method is 1. Convert your whole data to a matrix by using apply, 2. check every row of every column to see if it matches R's date format, 3. figure out which columns are either all Dates or NA, 4. convert those columns to date. I don't know how many rows you typically are pulling, but this is inefficient.

Comment: Rather than check *every row of every column*, maybe just check the first `x` rows. If missing data is relatively rare for you, checking the 5-10 rows is probably plenty. If missing data is more common, check the first 5-10 non-missing rows. And use the column classes of the data! You only need to check non-numeric columns to see if they are dates.

Comment: Similarly for your logicals - you don't need to check every row of every column. Check the top X rows, and only the non-numeric columns (and the non-Date columns) for `True/False`, and check only numeric columns for `0/1`.

Comment: And you should be using `lapply`, not `apply`. Get rid of your `if(size)` statements and use list subsetting of data frames, `df[cols] = lapply(df[cols], as.Date)`. It's not a bottleneck, but `%<>%` will be slightly slower than normal assignment. And you can simplify your regex pattern to `"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"`

Comment: Testing dates can be done with `sapply`, something like `date_cols = sapply(df, function(x) ...)`. Have `function(x)` return a logical, TRUE if date col, FALSE otherwise.

Comment: I guess I've written enough comments for an answer, when I find some time I'll edit this into a coherent answer.

Comment: Thanks! I made the date regex easier and changed to lapply, but I'm not sure to implement the rest.